# SQL query ALL "or more"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making an e-commerce and I have some troubles with the filtering by attributes.

I have 2 SQL tables (in fact 3 of them, for the ManyToMany relationship, let's just consider Product.attributes as a set of id):

```
Products (id: integer, name: string, attributes: relationship Many To Many to table attributes)
Attributes (id: integer, value: string)
```

My goal is to receive plenty of attributes ids, and get only the products that have exactly theses attributes or more, for example :

I have theses attributes:

```
Attribute(id: 1, name: 'Size M')
Attribute(id: 2, name: 'Size L')
Attribute(id: 3, name: 'Size XL')
```

I have theses products:

```
Product(id: 1, name: 'Tee-shirt 1', attributes: [1,2])
Product(id: 2, name: 'Tee-shirt 2', attributes: [1,2,3])
```

And I need to query for the attributes [1,2], so I should obtain my two products as result, and if I have attributes [1,2,3], I will have just 'Tee-shirt 2'

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN Attribute a ON a.id IN p.attributes 
WHERE a.id = ALL(SELECT * FROM Attribute WHERE id IN [1,2]);
```

The problem is that it works if the product has exactly and only theses two attributes 1 and 2, I need it to works also if there is more attributes at least that it contains the requested ones.

I hope it's clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your data structure makes no sense.  MySQL does not have columns that store multiple values.

Comment: Yes it's simplified as I said, in fact their is 3 tables, products, products_attributes, and products_products_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for all the product have attribute in (1,2)

So assuming you have a relationship  products_attributes Many To Many between table products and attributes

```
id, product_id, attribute_id
```

You could use

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN products_attributes pa ON pa_id.product_id = p.id 
where pa.attribute_id IN  (1,2)
group by p.id
having count(distinct pa.attribute_id ) >= 2
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you, it worked perfectly just changing : having count(distinct pa.attribute_id ) >= 2

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you have the search pattern as a string (which contains the ids in ascending order):

```
SET @s = '1,2';
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.attributes
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN Attributes a ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, p.attributes)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.id, @s)
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.attributes
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(a.id ORDER BY a.id) = @s
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ae3b136c65d9403ba905f0451c8e99a7).
Results:

```
> id | name        | attributes
> -: | :---------- | :---------
>  1 | Tee-shirt 1 | 1,2       
>  2 | Tee-shirt 2 | 1,2,3
```